# Is it possible to support the iPad1 but not the iPhone3GS?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have been looking at removing support for iPhone3GS for a title I am developing. I realise I can use the device capabilities to stop people using certain devices but I cant find a specific setting which would stop the support for only the 3GS?

Thanks

Comment: The title and your question contradict one another. Do you want to support the 3GS or not?

Comment: @Asheh Are you finded a solution? If Yes, please tell for us =)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect for a forward facing camera, which was introduced in the iPhone 4, with

```
if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable: 
         UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront ])
{
   // do something
} else {
   // you have an iPhone 3GS or less
}
```

I'm assuming you are not supporting models less than 4.  If not, and you only want to eliminate the 3GS specifically, but allow the iPhone 3G, you can check for video capability. 3GS has it, 3 and less don't.

Comment: I'm also assuming you already know how to detect iPhone vs. iPad and will adjust accordingly.

Comment: This doesnt really help as I dont want it to appear in the store at all. This is selective when the user has aleady downloaded the application?